# UITextField text not changing on the UI

Tags: uitextfield

Once the code bellow is executed, the textfield's text doesn't change in the UI to "Fly" but the second NSLog does print "TextField: Fly" as it should.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *typeTextField;
....

UITableViewCell* cell = [self.theTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TypeCell"];
self.typeTextField = (UITextField*)[cell viewWithTag:1];
NSLog(@"TextField: %@ ", self.typeTextField.text);
self.typeTextField.text = @"Fly";
NSLog(@"TextField: %@ ", self.typeTextField.text);
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost definitely forgot to connect the outlet for the UITextField in interface builder.  Bring up the .xib file that that `typeTextField` is visible in, click on typeTextField, then show the Utility pane (the one on the far right in Xcode 4+).  Click the Connections Inspector (the one that looks like a right arrow) and drag a New Referencing Outlet to your File's Owner.

When you don't connect the UITextField you drew in Interface Builder with the IBOutlet that you identified in your source file, both UITextFields get created as separate entities.  You can make changes and work with the valid typeTextField with a broken IBOutlet, but it'll never appear on your view.

Consult [How to connect an IBOutlet from an UITableViewController directly to custom cell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7988523/how-to-connect-an-iboutlet-from-an-uitableviewcontroller-directly-to-custom-cell) and http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d_kO-J3DYvc on properly wiring your custom UITableViewCell objects.

Comment: Hmmm...that's what I initially did but I got the error below...so I thought pointing to it would be enough...obviously don't no too much about XCode.  "Couldn't compile connection: <IBCocoaTouchOutletConnection:0x40183b0a0  <IBProxyObject: 0x401837f60> => typeTextField => <IBUITextField: 0x4018168a0>>"

Comment: Here's a movie on how to properly wire your IBOutlets for a custom UITableViewCell: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d_kO-J3DYvc  I did not create this movie.

Comment: Thanks. I've created custom cells that way before but with this cell I only use one instance of it so I thought it would be a waste to create a new class.